# Проблема с анимацией в safari и остальных браузерах

Tags: css, анимация, css-animation, transform

Есть код, представленный ниже, основная логика: справа на лево перемещается ul с вложенными слайдами li. 
Проблемы 2: 
1 - после завершения анимации, внешний вид возвращается в начальное состояние. 
2 - в сафари данная анимация работает через раз, или после перехода в другое окно и возвращение обратно. Хотелось бы, чтобы работало после каждого обновления страницы.

```css
-webkit-animation: cssAnimation 5s ease;
-moz-animation: cssAnimation 5s ease;
-o-animation: cssAnimation 5s ease;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
from { -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(100%); }
to { -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(-65%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes cssAnimation {
from { -moz-transform: scale(1) translate(100%); }
to { -moz-transform: scale(1) translate(-65%); }
}
@-o-keyframes cssAnimation {
from { -o-transform: scale(1) translate(100%); }
to { -o-transform: scale(1) translate(-65%); }
}
@keyframes cssAnimation {
from { transform: scale(1) translate(100%); }
to { transform: scale(1) translate(-65%); }
}
```

Comment: между `0.5s` и `ease` поставьте `infinite`

Answer (score 1):

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

данная строка решила проблему возврата в начальное состояние.

А по сафари проблема решилась при натяжке

Answer (score -2):

я сутки не мог понять в чем проблема, спасибо тебе чел

animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*when the spec is finished*/

-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/

-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*FF 5+*/

-o-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*Not implemented yet*/

-ms-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*IE 10+*/

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой типа «спасибо». когда ваша [репутация](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [проголосовать за вопросы и ответы](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), которые сочтёте полезными. а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите